# What is the idiomatic way to write Rust microservice with shared db connections and caches?

Tags: concurrency, rust, mutex, shared-ptr

I'm writing my first `Rust` microservice with `hyper`. After years of development in `C++` and `Go` I tend to use controller for processing requests (like here - https://github.com/raycad/go-microservices/blob/master/src/user-microservice/controllers/user.go) where the controller stores shared data like db connection pool and different kinds of cache. 
I know, with `hyper`, I can write it this way:

```
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response};

pub struct Controller {
//    pub cache: Cache,
//    pub db: DbConnectionPool
}

impl Controller {
    pub fn echo(&mut self, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
        // extensively using db and cache here...
        let mut response = Response::new(Body::empty());
        *response.body_mut() = req.into_body();
        Ok(response)
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
use hyper::{Server, Request, Response, Body, Error};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};

use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr, sync::Arc, sync::Mutex};

async fn route(controller: Arc<Mutex<Controller>>, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let mut c = controller.lock().unwrap();
    c.echo(req)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let controller = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Controller{}));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(move |_conn| {
        let controller = Arc::clone(&controller);
        async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |req| {
                let c = Arc::clone(&controller);
                route(c, req)
            }))
        }
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

Since the compiler doesn't let me share mutable structure between threads I got to use `Arc<Mutex<T>>` idiom. But I'm afraid the `let mut c = controller.lock().unwrap();` part would block the entire controller while processing single request, i.e. there's no concurrency here. 
What is the idiomatic way to address this problem?

Comment: What methods on `DbConnectionPool` are you using? If those methods don't need `&mut self`, you can change `echo` to `&self`.

Comment: Usually database pools have their own locks, and you don't need to implement your own locks to use them. For example, [`r2d2::Pool::get`](https://docs.rs/r2d2/0.8.8/r2d2/struct.Pool.html#method.get) takes a `&self` instead of a `&mut self` even though it potentially adds a new connection to the pool.

Comment: I understand that particular implementations of connection pool may be `const`. But I'd like to know what to do in general. Let it be not connection pools, but `hashmap`s, for example.

Comment: Then do Arc Mutex on the hashmap, and also Arc Mutex on each entry of the hashmap.

Comment: @SOFe thanks, that worked for me! Could you please write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&mut` always acquires a (compile time or runtime) exclusive lock to the value.
Only acquire a `&mut` at the exact scope you want to get locked.
If a value owned by the locked value needs separate locking management,
wrap it in a `Mutex`.

Assuming your `DbConnectionPool` is structured like this:

```
struct DbConnectionPool {
    conns: HashMap<ConnId, Conn>,
}
```

We need to `&mut` the `HashMap` when we add/remove items on the `HashMap`, 
but we don't need to `&mut` the value in `Conn`.
So `Arc` allows us to *separate the mutability boundary from its parent*,
and `Mutex` allows us to *add its own interior mutability*.

Moreover, our `echo` method doesn't want to be `&mut`,
so another layer of interior mutability needs to be added on the `HashMap`.

So we change this to

```
struct DbConnectionPool {
    conns: Mutex<HashMap<ConnId, Arc<Mutex<Conn>>>,
}
```

Then when you want to get a connection,

```
fn get(&self, id: ConnId) -> Arc<Mutex<Conn>> {
    let mut pool = self.db.conns.lock().unwrap(); // ignore error if another thread panicked
    if let Some(conn) = pool.get(id) {
        Arc::clone(conn)
    } else {
        // here we will utilize the interior mutability of `pool`
        let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(new_conn()));
        pool.insert(id, Arc::clone(&arc));
        arc
    }
}
```

(the `ConnId` param and the if-exists-else logic is used to simplify the code; you can change the logic)

On the returned value you can do

```
self.get(id).lock().unwrap().query(...)
```

For convenient illustration I changed the logic to user supplying the ID.
In reality, you should be able to find a `Conn` that has not been acquired and return it.
Then you can return a RAII guard for `Conn`,
similar to how `MutexGuard` works,
to auto free the connection when user stops using it.

Also consider using `RwLock` instead of `Mutex` if that might result in a performance boost.